# GPU Spatial Clustering

Tags: algorithm, webgl

I have a around 100k points on the screen (that might update). 2D points.

The goal is to cluster them into groups, by a constant distance. Meaning, finding groups of points that the distance between them is less than this distance. Instead of drawing those points, a big point will be drawn there with a number on it.

The problem is the calculation time.
Tried many algorithms on CPU, but didn't get the performances i wished for.

I'm trying to find an algorithm to solve this problem in the GPU using WebGL-GLSL, when texture contains all my locations.

Can be single draw phase or multiple.. as long as i achieve better calculation time than i get with the CPU.

Comment: are you trying to do it per frame, or just once?  What is an upper limit the calc can take?

Comment: It is not per frame, but points are moving which means cluster is invalid, so i must performing the cluster calculation again, and for not harming the performances I've decided to try moving it to the GPU (if it is possible). I have in addition zoom option. which mean i need to calculate for the zooms as well. What do you mean `upper limit` ?

Comment: I just meant, is it ok if the calc takes 1 second, or should it be under 50 milliseconds.  Also, if you could list the CPU algorithms you tried, there may be some you missed.

Comment: My algo in the CPU is very simple. not the best accurate though. but it is good enough. Creating a kdtree from the objects. Searching the closest to the first. and then marking them as `clustered`. and continue this loop on not used `clustered` objects. It is very fast for one zoom. but my user can go trough 20 zooms, meaning 20 different clustering distances. and here is the problem. Together it is around 300 ms. Between zoom to zoom, i'm removing from the calculation the objects that are not clustered at all. so i have every round less objects to calculate.